# PHP mail not sending email to facebook User

Tags: php, facebook, email

I am trying to send email to user who have registered in my website with their facebook mail.
But now they complaining, they are not receving any email in their message folder.

My Email :-

```
mail("username@facebook.com", "Someone Commented on your Topic", $msg, "From: no-reply@mywebsite.com");
```

`$msg` is certain message.

This script works perfectly for gmail, yahoomail , but for facebook, this is not working.

**Note:** I don't have any facebook application for my website, nor i have anything to do with facebook application, it has simple signup form, where some people are providing their facebook email address, and than the story continues as above.

Do, i need to modify any thing in header or do i need to create some sorts of facebook application to enable mail getting received to users.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a facebook email address to test? That will save you some trouble. It's always possible they aren't finding it or put their email address in wrong.

Comment: i didn't get you ? "facebook email address to test ?" Actually i tested with my facebook email, and i found I am not receving mail and its more than 1 week now..

Answer (score 0):

Messages sent outside Facebook's infrastructure and/or from non-friends get slotted into a hard-to-find "Others" inbox.

Comment: Then Facebook is likely blocking you as spammy. There's unlikely to be much you can do about it. Check your web server's logs.